# WARN[0000] The "jc" variable is not set

Tags: docker-compose

I updated my docker compose. when I ran every `docker compose` command, at first of all responses I got this warning.

```
WARN[0000] The "jc" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Do you have any idea?

It doesn't happen in the past.